# Wiring solar panels and battery bank

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging, solar-charge-controller

I have 4 12v batteries, and 2 mppt charge controllers. I want to run the batteries in a series to get 48v. The two charge controllers are 12/24v output. Is it possible to charge 2 batteries with each controller while they are still in the series?

I could buy a single charge control that will do 48v but i already have these two on hand.

Comment: Maybe. It depends on how the charge controllers work. You could make your question better and easier to answer if you edit it to include the details about the charge controllers (manufacturer and model number) and also battery size (in Amp-hours). I assume they are some type of 12V lead batteries. If not you should specify what type of batteries they are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can connect the 4 batteries in series. Each pair connected to a 24 V charge controller. But just to make it sure, you also need to check if you have to connect two solar panels in series if you want to use the charge controller in 24 V mode.

**Word of caution**: You need both the charge controllers connected to **different** panels. You CANNOT connect a single panel to two charge controllers and then connect the output of the charge controllers in series. It will create a short circuit and risk of fire. I hope you already know this, just writing for the worst case.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhAcCt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>